# Ruby on Rails - insert future date in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date, timestamp

I want to insert a date in my database where the date is in the future (i.e. expiry date). A year from now. The dates are not submitted via the web, but every record created has a one year to expire and I want to add that manually in the database when the record is created. i.e.

```
@certificate.expiry_date = time.now + one_year
```

I would also appreciate a full documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

```
Time.now + 1.year
```

should do the trick. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Integer/year) for further information.